# Ruby on Rails - Need Help Optimizing My horrible code involving multiple data models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, optimization, plsql

I am working on a personal project and I have hit a wall. I know I am writing bad code and I really wan to refactor the code below. The application has three tables on the same page. Each table contains data from a has-many-though relationship. In essence I have an employees page which contains three tables of employee licenses that all expire in grouped intervals:

ALL EMPLOYEE PAGE

- Employees with licenses Expiring in 30 days
- Employees with licenses Expiring in 30-90 days
- Employees with licenses Expiring in 90 days

All three of these tables are independently paginated and I am allowing the user to enter a search term and search across all three tables.

However I have over 1200 licenses so the page is taking forever to load. How can I optimize this functionality? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Model

```
  def self.emp_lic_small
   self.all.map{|se| se.employee_licenses.less_than_thirty}.flatten
  end

  def self.emp_lic_medium
    self.all.map{|se| se.employee_licenses.between_thirty_and_ninty}.flatten
  end

  def self.emp_lic_large
    self.all.map{|se| se.employee_licenses.greater_than_ninty}.flatten
  end
```

### Controller

```
    @small_employee_licenses = SiteEmployee.search(params[:search]).emp_lic_small.paginate(:page => params[:small_lic], :per_page => 20)
    @medium_employee_licenses = SiteEmployee.search(params[:search]).emp_lic_medium.paginate(:page => params[:med_lic], :per_page => 20)
    @large_employee_licenses = SiteEmployee.search(params[:search]).emp_lic_large.paginate(:page => params[:large_lic], :per_page => 20)
```

### View

```
<div class="panel panel-danger">
  <div class="panel-heading"><strong>Employee Licenses Expiring in Less Than 30 Days</strong></div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <th class="text-center">Employee Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Employed By</th>
            <th class="text-center">License Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Expiration Date</th>
            <th class="text-center">Obtained?</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% if @small_employee_licenses.present? %>
                <% @small_employee_licenses.each do |e| %>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= link_to e.site_employee.to_s, site_employee_path(e.site_employee)%></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= link_to e.site_employee.site.name, site_path(e.site_employee.site)%></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= e.license.name %></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= e.expiration_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= e.obtained? ? "Yes" : "No" %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <%end%>
            <% else %>
                <tr><td colspan="3">There are currently no Licenses due in the next 30 days.</td></tr>
            <% end %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<%= will_paginate @small_employee_licenses, param_name:'small_lic' unless @small_employee_licenses.blank?  %> 

<div class="panel panel-warning">
  <div class="panel-heading"><strong>Employee Licenses Expiring in 30-90 Days</strong></div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <th class="text-center">Employee Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Employed By</th>
            <th class="text-center">License Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Expiration Date</th>
            <th class="text-center">Obtained?</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% if @medium_employee_licenses.present? %>
                <% @medium_employee_licenses.each do |e| %>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= link_to e.site_employee.to_s, site_employee_path(e.site_employee)%></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= link_to e.site_employee.site.name, site_path(e.site_employee.site)%></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= e.license.name %></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= e.expiration_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= e.obtained? ? "Yes" : "No" %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <%end%>
            <% else %>
                <tr><td colspan="3">There are currently no Licenses due in the next 30 days.</td></tr>
            <% end %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<%= will_paginate @medium_employee_licenses, param_name:'med_lic' unless @medium_employee_licenses.blank?  %> 
<div class="panel panel-success">
  <div class="panel-heading"><strong>Employee Licenses Expiring in 30-90 Days</strong></div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <th class="text-center">Employee Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Employed By</th>
            <th class="text-center">License Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Expiration Date</th>
            <th class="text-center">Obtained?</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% if @large_employee_licenses.present? %>
                <% @large_employee_licenses.each do |e| %>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= link_to e.site_employee.to_s, site_employee_path(e.site_employee)%></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= link_to e.site_employee.site.name, site_path(e.site_employee.site)%></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= e.license.name %></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= e.expiration_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= e.obtained? ? "Yes" : "No" %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <%end%>
            <% else %>
                <tr><td colspan="3">There are currently no Licenses due in the next 30 days.</td></tr>
            <% end %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<%= will_paginate @large_employee_licenses, param_name:'large_lic' unless @large_employee_licenses.blank?  %>
```

Comment: Try: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ah thank you. I did not know this was a thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you have single model and related DB table `licenses` where you'd have column `expiring`. In particular column you can do some enum marking licences "30 days", "30-89 days", "90+ days".
I imagine it could look something like this:

```
class License < ApplicationRecord
  #probaly this model has_many / balongs_to something

  enum expiring: { 30_days: 1, 30_89_days: 2, 90_days: 3}

end
```

Then you can query to retreive records according to particular `expiring` value. If you need to populate values in 3 tables, I guess you can retreive them from single table and then by that `expiring` column split accordingly. My thinking would be do everything in single table, which then visually you can split in 3.

In addition for better performance you can check [Ajax Datatables gem](https://github.com/antillas21/ajax-datatables-rails).

Comment: This is a great Idea! Thank you for the suggestion. I like the idea of having a master table that basically pre-caches all of the data. That way I can just pull and scope the data as apposed to aggregating on demand. The only other concern I have is I am using the apartment gem which makes some of these external tables/models a bit more chaotic.

Oh and I up-voted your response but stack overflow said I didnt have enough XP.

Comment: @MarcoMayhem Glad it helps. One more thing - maybe you can use partials in view - [here is more info](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials). 1) it would make your code look more professional; 2) tables can be populated with some AJAX which should increase performance as well.